# Kafka Connect Elasticsearch sink no documents are indexed

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to set up a test to move data from MySQL to Elasticsearch.

I have a dockerized setup with broker, zookeeper, connect, ksql server and cli, schema registry and Elasticsearch. I'm using the docker images from confluent version *5.1.0* and for Elasticsearch I'm using *elasticsearch:6.5.4*

I configured a **JDBC connector** to get data from MySQL into Kafka, this is working I see my topics created and using ksql-cli I can see the new messages in the stream as I update rows in MySQL.

I also configured an **Elasticsearch sink connector** the connector is created successfully and the index in Elasticsearch is also there, but I see **no documents in my Elasticsearch index**.

This is the ES sink connector configuration:

```
{
    "name": "es-connector",
    "config": {
            "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
            "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
            "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
            "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
            "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081",
            "connection.url": "http://es:9200",
            "type.name": "_doc",
            "topics": "test_topic",
            "drop.invalid.message": true,
            "behavior.on.null.values": "ignore",
            "behavior.on.malformed.documents": "ignore",
            "schema.ignore": true
    }
}
```

This is what I see when I query the status of the sink connector: `curl -X GET  http://connect:8083/connectors/es-connector`

```
{
    "name": "es-connector",
    "connector": {
        "state": "RUNNING",
        "worker_id": "connect:8083"
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "state": "RUNNING",
            "id": 0,
            "worker_id": "connect:8083"
        }
    ],
    "type": "sink"
}
```

In Elasticsearch I can see the index `http://es:9200/test_topic/_search`

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

I keep making updates and inserts in MySQL, I see the messages in the stream using ksql-cli but no documents are created in Elasticsearch. I even created a topic manually using `kafka-avro-console-producer` and published messages, then created a second sink connector for this topic and the same result, I see the index but no documents.

I see no errors in kafka-connect so I don't understand why is not working. Is there something wrong with the connector configuration? Am I missing something?

Edit:

For the Elasticsearch sink configuration I tried with and without these lines:

```
"drop.invalid.message": true,
"behavior.on.null.values": "ignore",
"behavior.on.malformed.documents": "ignore",
"schema.ignore": true
```

And the result is the same, no documents.

**Edit**

I found the error:

> Key is used as document id and cannot be null

.

Comment: Could you add sample message, that is used as source for Elasticsearch sink Connector?

Comment: @wardziniak I dont see why this is important but here it is, for the jdbc connector a message looks like: `{"email", "some@some.com"}`and for the ad-hoc topic I created a message looks like `{"f1":"value1"}`

Comment: I would suggest to increase log level for Kafka Connect and check in log the content of records, maybe they are nulls

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
"key.ignore": true
```

the Elasticsearch sink will use the topic+partition+offset as the Elasticsearch document ID. As you found, you will get a new document for *every* message.

With

```
"key.ignore": false
```

the Elasticsearch sink will use the *Key of the Kafka message* as the Elasticsearch document ID. If you don't have a key in your Kafka message, you will understandably get the error `Key is used as document id and cannot be null`. You can use various methods for setting the key in a Kafka message, including Single Message Transform to set the Kafka message key if you're ingesting through Kafka Connect, [detailed here](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-3/).